# ddrescue: How to retry for 1 bad block after all other data is safely stored?

Tags: data-recovery, ddrescue

I used `ddrescue` yesterday hopefully to retrieve 1:1 copy and stored it as an image on a new drive. Suppose I read backwards, because I knew, that there is a bad cluster at the beginning of the failing drive, i.e. with `-R` switch, from man page:

> ```
> -R
> --reverse
> ```
>
> Reverse the direction of all passes (copying, trimming, scraping and retrying). Every pass that is normally run forwards will now be run backwards, and vice versa. '`--reverse`' does not modify the size of the blocks copied during each phase, just the order in which they are tried.

Of course, I used `mapfile` to be able to restart the process.

Plus, I used direct access, not all drives are supposed to support this, but mine does.

---

The complete command line I used follows:

```
ddrescue -d -R /dev/sdb baddrive.ddrescue.img baddrive.ddrescue.log
```

The result is 1 error 4096 bytes in size.

---

Relevant part of the `mapfile` follows:

```
# current_pos  current_status
0x1375BCE00     +
#      pos        size  status
0x00000000  0x1375BC000  +
0x1375BC000  0x00001000  -
0x1375BD000  0xE7A97F9000  +
```

---

## Question

Is it possible to retry for the bad cluster like 100 times just to be sure it is totally dead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

You need to modify the `mapfile`'s line:

```
0x1375BC000  0x00001000  -
```

to contain question mark at the end like so:

```
0x1375BC000  0x00001000  ?
```

---

Now you are ready to restart the recovery process, you just need to add the retry option there:

> ```
> -r n
> --retry-passes=n
> ```
>
> Exit after the given number of retry passes. Defaults to 0. -1 means infinity. Every bad sector is tried only once in each pass. To retry bad sectors detected on a previous run, you must specify a non-zero number of retry passes.

Comment: There's no need to edit the mapfile. As the documentation you quote says, bad sectors detected in a previous run will be retried if you specify a non-zero number of retry passes.